# Using find to find symlinks that point to a certain pattern of files

Tags: find, symlink

I have several directories that all have various symlinks in them. I want find (or another program) to find based on where the symlinks point to. For example this is how it currently works:

```
└─(11:05:%)── ll slink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dialout 9 2010-11-03 11:05 slink -> /opt/file
└─(11:05:%)── find / -name 'file'
```

This is what I'd like to be able to do

```
└─(11:05:%)── find . -name 'file'
/slink -> /opt/file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -L -name 'file'
```

-L means follow symbolic links and according to man it takes properties from this file. Alternativly you can write:

```
find . -lname 'file'
```

The second option will work with broken links.

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. I think `-lname` is better; `-L` will cause it to follow symlinks and to return normal files with the given name, while `-lname` is exactly the desired behavior. It won't match in this case though because the symlink's target is `/opt/file`, so you need to either do `find . -lname '/opt/file'` or `find . -lname '*/file'`

Comment: This works, except the find on the busybox machine I was working on didn't have the -L parameter =\

Comment: I think the first option is better dealt with at http://serverfault.com/a/87643/96883